# How to set automatically font size change of UIButton regardless of the orientation of the device?

Tags: xcode, uibutton, storyboard, font-size

I want to have my buttons changes font size, when user change orientation.
Is it possible to do it in storyboard?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are targeting an old iOS version, don't use the word "orientation". They are called "[size classes](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/size-classes/)" now. You should work with *them* instead of orientations.

In the storyboard's property inspector, there is a little "+" next to the font property:

[image]

If you click that, you can add a new value for font when it is changed to a specific size class:

[image]

Here I made the font size bigger if it is horizontally regular:

[image]

IMO, you shouldn't change the font size depending on the size class and/or orientation. There might be something wrong with your design...